# Division with str, float, int, and tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, I want to be able to divide int, str, tuple, and float in half. I'm having trouble with distinguishing the type of an input and then returning the same type.

For example, half(7) should return 3 (not 3.0!), half(9.0) should return 4.5, half("seventeen") should return "seve", and half((1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) should return (1,2,3).  I have tried this code without success:

```
def half(x):
    """returns half of the input, rounded down

    str -> str, int -> int, float -> float, tuple -> tuple"""
    return int(x/2)
    if x is float:
        return float(x/2)
    if x is tuple:
        return tuple(x/2)
    if x is str:
        return str(x/2)
```

Comment: `x is float` tells you whether or not `x` is *exactly the same object* as `float` (which it is pretty unlikely to be). Did you mean `if isinstance(x, float)` (i.e. if `x` is an instance of the `float` class)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to check types. Secondly, this code assumes you're using Python 2.

```
def half(x):

    if type(x) == float:
        return x / 2

    if type(x) == int:
        return x // 2

    if type(x) in (tuple, str):
         return x[:len(x)//2]
```

Comment: `isinstance(x, (float, int))` would be generally preferred

Comment: In Python 3, `4 / 2 == 2.0` - not what is wanted.

Comment: Jon, what would be the purpose of the `type` function if it is not preferred?

Answer (score 6):

Just use [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch), which chooses the implementation based on the type of the first argument:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def half(x):
    raise TypeError()

@half.register(int)
def _(x):
    return x // 2

@half.register(float)
def _(x):
    return x / 2

@half.register(tuple)
def _(x):
    return x[:len(x) // 2]

@half.register(str)
def _(x):
    return x[:len(x) // 2]
```

You can shorten this to passing lambdas to `half.register` instead of using decorators and function statements if you prefer so:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def half(x):
    raise TypeError()

half.register(int, lambda x: x // 2)
half.register(float, lambda x: x / 2)
half.register(tuple, lambda x: x[:len(x) // 2])
half.register(str, lambda x: x[:len(x) // 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict with type as key and lambda as value using `//` for ints and `/` for floats and simply indexing for str and tuple `len(x)//2`.

```
def half(i):
    d = {float: lambda x: x/2, int: lambda x: x//2, str: lambda x: x[:len(x)//2:], tuple: lambda x: x[:len(x)//2]}
    return d.get(type(i), lambda x: "Invalid input")(i)

In [29]: print(half(7))
3   
In [30]: print(half((1,2,3,4,5,6,7)))
(1, 2, 3)
In [31]: print(half("seventeen") )
seve
In [32]: print( half(9.0))
4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numbers

def half(x):
    if isinstance(x, numbers.Integral):
        return x // 2
    elif isinstance(x, numbers.Real):
        return x / 2.
    elif isinstance(x, (tuple, str)):
        return x[:len(x) // 2]
    else:
        raise TypeError("x should be an int, float, tuple, or str (or derived from one of those)")
```

Comment: it would be `import numbers` and `str` as there is no basestring in `python3`